# Google Apps Script & Docs: Unable to copy Drops Down from one google doc to another

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, dropdown

Here is the sample of the code that I am using to copy one google doc (template/source) to another google doc (target). It is able to copy all types of elements other than Drop Downs.

```
function copyDoc(sourceDocID, targetDocID, docBody,insertIndex) {
  
  var targetDoc = DocumentApp.openById(targetDocID);
  var sourceDoc = DocumentApp.openById(sourceDocID);
  var sourceDocBody = sourceDoc.getBody();
  var totalElements = sourceDoc.getNumChildren();

  
  for (var j = 0; j < totalElements; ++j) {
    var element = sourceDocBody.getChild(j).copy();
    var type = element.getType();
    switch (type) {
      case DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH:
        docBody.insertParagraph(insertIndex + j, element);
        break;
      case DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE:
        docBody.insertTable(insertIndex + j, element);
        break;
      case DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM:
        var glyphType = element.getGlyphType();
        docBody.insertListItem(insertIndex + j, element);
        element.setGlyphType(glyphType);
        break;
      // Add other conditions (headers, footers, etc.) here...
      default:
        // Handle unknown element types here...
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

The ElementType for google doc dropdowns is also PARAGRAPH, so ideally it should get copied. The target doc shows the copied dropdown, but from what it appears the options within the dropdown are not getting copied to the target, hence the dropdown does not work and gives an error. It only shows the default/selected option in the source in the copied dropdown.

[Error Message on Google Doc's when You click the DropDown in the Target Google Doc.] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2NlU.png)